# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Not recognizing Bluetooth Microsoft Sculp Touch Mouse

Tags: windows, mouse, bluetooth

I've been working for a while with Ubuntu, but I am trying to get working my Microsoft Bluetooth Sculp Touch Mouse for a while and tried different answers I found on internet, but nothing seems to work.

Could you help with this please?